# What are the FAA regulations on lighting for ultralight vehicles?

Tags: faa-regulations, ultralight, aircraft-lighting

I'm in the process of scoping out a project involving an ultralight vehicle and some Neo pixel LEDs.

In the US, there are many regulations for lights on cars. Things like the location on the vehicle, the direction, color and blink rate are all regulated.

What lighting laws apply to ultralight vehicles, as far as location, direction, color and blink rate?

Comment: Hopefully you don't plan on flying at night since, in states other than Alaska, flying an ultralight at night is against the law.

Comment: @RonBeyer except 30 minutes before / after, and in G airspace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultralights are regulated under [14 CFR 103](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr103_main_02.tpl) and there are very few regulations of any kind that apply to them.

The only specific lighting requirement is in [103.11(b)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=2fa6d81236b478369ed8860c5a973dce&mc=true&node=se14.2.103_111&rgn=div8):

> **§103.11   Daylight operations.**
>
> (a) No person may operate an ultralight vehicle except between the
>   hours of sunrise and sunset.
>
> (b) Notwithstanding paragraph (a) of this section, ultralight vehicles
>   may be operated during the twilight periods 30 minutes before official
>   sunrise and 30 minutes after official sunset or, in Alaska, during the
>   period of civil twilight as defined in the Air Almanac, if:
>
> (1) The vehicle is equipped with an operating anticollision light
>   visible for at least 3 statute miles; and
>
> (2) All operations are conducted in uncontrolled airspace.

[This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/64/62) and [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14444/62) have some information about what an anticollision light actually is (a beacon and/or strobe), but since ultralights are so lightly regulated I'd be surprised if anyone cares much about the exact form of lighting. However, you could check with your local EAA chapter or ultralight club to see what people typically use.